# java running form table update problem form application

Tags: java, forms, jtable, jscrollpane

Hey i need your help about the [code below](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java). i m using netbeans, i have a user interface and i need to update a existing scrollpane with that table i have created dynamically but i cant find any way to do that for last 3 days could you help me out at this point?

```
dbcon.Connect();

String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Sport",
            "# of Years",
            "Vegetarian"};
Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}};

 DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
 JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
 // i created this table and can't update an existing Jscrollpane :(
```

exactly i need a way to refill a table of repaint a new table to an existing scroll pane

Any idea?

Comment: The [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java) from which (most of) this was copied works correctly. If this is a real question, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the question correctly, the poster wants to update an "existing" scroll pane.

If this is the case then you just do:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( table );
```

However, if you already have a table in the scrollpane then you don't even need to create a new JTable. All you need to do is update the model of the table:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...);
table.setModel( model ):
```

Comment: YES YES YES thats what i wanted.
Thanks a lot my friend  :))

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at the JScrollPane [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)?  I think doing something like this should work:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
table = new JTable(dtm);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: thats the problem i cant use tis.add on netbeans it does not allow me to do that because i automatically craete the  UI codes and i need to update an existing scrollpane or table

Comment: @Utku if a "feature" of an IDE hinders you, dont use it ;-) @Kyle not a solution to the problem as I understood (my understanding could be wrong, of course) it: it's about dynamically updating/setting the _data_ In such a context re-creating the view is wrong.